# Analytics custom variables

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I'm trying to make a custom report.
I've just put some test code on my main page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12323748-3']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
  2,                   // This custom var is set to slot #1
  'Test_var',     // The name acts as a kind of category for the user activity
  'Yes',               // This value of the custom variable
  2                    // Sets the scope to session-level
   ]);

  (function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

My custom report setup looks like this:
http://updo.nl/file/ed351e11.png

However, it just comes up as empty (I let it gather data for 2 days before checking the report)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try using 'Custom Variable (Value 2)' instead of 'Custom Variable (Key 2)'.

Comment: I did, but that gives the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've asked much the same question. I've been told that you have to put the setCustomVar line above the trackPageView line and below the var _gaq line.  Like this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12323748-3']);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Test_var', 'Yes', 2]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

_trackPageview sends all of the information to Google Analytics, so you can't add information after its already sent.